# Where can I download the /usr/dict/ packages?

Tags: package-management

I am looking for free lists of words in multiple languages.

I understand that linux distributions do have such lists in `/usr/share/dict`. Is it possible to download these from somewhere without having to install linux? Tar balls (or equivalent) would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can look at [GNU's aspell dictionary list](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/)

Or simply install the sources for the packages, which will give you what these have been made from.

Answer (score 4):

There are several free dictionary databases, if I gather correctly that this is what you're after.

The ones [Debian GNU/Linux provides](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=freedict&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all) (in `/usr/share/opendict/dictionaries`) are from [**FreeDict**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeDict) (also [see here](http://freedict.org/), and [here for tarballs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freedict/files/)).

Answer (score 3):

Mike Chirico compiled an enormous [English word list](http://sourceforge.net/projects/souptonuts/files/souptonuts/dictionary/linuxwords.1.tar.gz/download).  Having such an enormous list can make a difference in some applications.